# C++, struct with pointers, create first object

Tags: c++, struct

I have a following struct Car:

```
struct Car {
public:
    integer number;
 Car  *down,  *right;
  Car(double a, Car b,  Car f): number(a), right(&f){}
};
```

For instance, I want to model something like a chain of cars and each car has a pointer to the next car.
My problem is that the first car should point to nowhere, to NULL.
(variable number has nothing to do with the position of a car in a chain).
I tried something like this:

```
Car* first = new Car(23421,NULL);
```

```
car.cpp:39:35: error: no matching function for call to ‘Car::Car(int, NULL)’ 
car.cpp:39:35: note: candidates are:
car.cpp:28:3: note: Car::Car(int, Car)
car.cpp:28:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘int’ to ‘Car’
car.cpp:24:8: note: Car::Car(const Car&)
car.cpp:24:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
```

How can I point to a nowhere?

Comment: Too many bugs in one piece of code. Start by changing `Car(double a, Car b,  Car f)` to `Car(double a, Car* b,  Car* f)`, but it's not good either; you will likely rewrite this code completely.

Comment: you might want to look into constructors, pointers, references, and method overloading

Comment: Seems like you're new to C++ and have made tons of mistakes, make Car store the attributes that make up a Car, then store them in a std::list rather than inventing your own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare a Car variable and assign the pointer members to NULL. This should be done in the default constructor so you don't have to do it manually each time.

```
Car mycar;
    mycar.down =NULL;
    mycar.right =NULL;
```

than, later you can chain your cars as you wish:

```
mycar.down = mySecondCar;
mycar.right = myThirdCar;
```

Comment: this might be a dup of a comment

Answer (score 0):

This constructor

```
Car(double a, Car b,  Car f): number(a), right(&f){}
```

is invalid. You use pointers to local variables. Change the constructor the following way

```
Car(double a, Car *b,  Car *f): number(a), right(f){}
```

Comment: this might be a dup of a comment